# wmi. Find out the model and size of the hard drive

Tags: vb.net, wmi

Good day!

There is the following function, with which I display information from certain wmi classes.

```vb
Private Function GetDetails(ByVal pcname As String, ByVal ClassName As String, ByVal Selection As String) As String
        Dim tmpstr As String = ""
        Dim myScope As New ManagementScope("\\" & pcname & "\root\cimv2")
        Dim oQuery As New SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM " & ClassName)
        Dim oResults As New ManagementObjectSearcher(myScope, oQuery)
        For Each queryObj As ManagementObject In oResults.Get()
            Try
                tmpstr = queryObj(Selection)
            Catch ex As Exception
                tmpstr = ""
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
        Next
        Return tmpstr
    End Function
```

That's how I use it.

```vb
Dim HardDriveName As String = GetDetails(PC, "Win32_DiskDrive", "Caption")
Dim HardDriveSize As String = GetDetails(PC, "Win32_DiskDrive", "Size")
```

The problem arises in the fact that several hard drives can be installed on a PC. Tell me how to display information on all hard drives?
I understand that you need to use a loop. But I don't understand how to do it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution for myself:

```vb
  Private Sub HardInfo(ByVal pcname As String)
        Dim myScope As New ManagementScope("\\" & pcname & "\root\cimv2")
        Dim oQuery As New SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive")
        Dim searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher(myScope, oQuery)
        Dim i As Integer
        For Each drive As ManagementObject In searcher.Get()
            i += 1
            MsgBox("Hard # " & i, drive("Caption") & "(" & Reformat_TB_GB_MB(drive("Size")) & ")")
        Next drive
    End Sub


    ' Reformat as TB, GB or MB (if needed)
    Private Function Reformat_TB_GB_MB(ByRef Value As Long)
        If Len(Value.ToString) > 12 Then ' Reformat if TB
            Return Format(Value / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024, "##0.00 TB")
        ElseIf Len(Value.ToString) > 9 Then ' Reformat if GB
            Return Format(Value / 1024 / 1024 / 1024, "###,##0.00 GB")
        ElseIf Len(Value.ToString) > 6 Then  ' Reformat if MB
            Return Format(Value / 1024 / 1024, "###,###,##0.00 MB")
        ElseIf Len(Value.ToString) > 3 Then  ' Reformat if KB
            Return Format(Value / 1024, "###,###,###,##0.00 KB")
        Else
            Return Format(Value, "###,###,###,###,##0.00 Bytes")
        End If
    End Function
```